# Web application in Golang for offline/browser use

Tags: go

I'd like to create a simple web application to manage some data. The application will use PostgreSQL but I have no idea how to package everything in order to make it run on windows, linux, and mac. I can cross-compile a go binary which will include everything (web server, etc..) but the postgresql database will be left out because that's running as a separate server locally. I heard about docker but I don't know if that's the right solution.

Should I create a docker container and include PostgreSQL in it so I can start that web app on any platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Docker to do this.

It complicates things since your users will have to install the Docker engine first. Go is perfectly capable for cross platform applications, batteries included.

Decide if you want your app to run in a browser tab or should it have it's own window?

For a **browser tab** compile your app for the target architecture and think about a URL scheme that will make sense to your users, for example

- `localhost:8080/app` => the user interface. This route is the web app, it serves HTML, JS and CSS. Tell your users to run the executable (or install it as a service, see [this](https://github.com/kardianos/service) or use a platform specific tool like [this one](https://nssm.cc)). Then open the link in a browser
- `localhost:8080/api` => backend routes. Serves data to requests made by the user interface. For talking to the Postgres server running locally

If you want your app to run in it's **own window** have a look at [Electron](https://electronjs.org). <s>See [gotron](https://github.com/Equanox/gotron): *Go Api for Electron*</s>

Comment: Thank you mozey. That's very true and I perfectly agree with you. One thing that bothers me is the database. PostgreSQL has it own running process/server and can't be bundled into a GO binary. So, I think SQLITE or something similar that is file based would be a better choice in my case.

Comment: It sounded like the client will already have Postgres as a "separate server locally". SQLite is a great option if you need to bundle a single user relational db, and it's well supported in golang

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Docker for this, you have to create a platform-specific docker image containing the platform-specific binary in it. Once you have these images, you can use docker-compose to run your app with an instance of postgres running in its own container.